# Выборка совпадений из одного столбца для заданных значений из другого

Tags: php, mysql

Вот так выглядит таблица

[image: таблица в mysql]

Надо вывести повторяющиеся значения по заданным разным `category_id` для одного и того же `product_id`.

Выборка по `category_id` == `65` и `66`, с условием тем, что вывести `product_id` == `60`, так как он попадает под оба условия равенства `category_id`. Остальные результаты `product_id` отсекаются.

Запрос типа

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM table WHERE category_id IN ('65','66')
```

или

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM table WHERE category_id = 65 AND 66
```

не совсем подходит, так как выводит и другие `product_id`.

Comment: Что-то не пойму, какое содержимое запроса должно вернуться? 1 строка со значение `60`?

Comment: Да верно, одна строка. Т.е. значение product_id, которое попадает и в оба равенства category_id

Comment: так у вас сейчас первый запрос из вопроса и так возвращает `60`!

Comment: @Visman, этот запрос возвращает не только `60`, но и ещё четыре значения: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc37/3

Comment: @alexander barakin, проглядел остальные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо объединить таблицу саму с собой. примерно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc37/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (pid int, cid int);
insert into t values
   (50, 76)
  ,(52, 65)
  ,(52, 67)
  ,(52, 76)
  ,(58, 65)
  ,(58, 76)
  ,(60, 65)
  ,(60, 66)
  ,(61, 67)
  ,(61, 76)
  ,(66, 62)
  ,(66, 66)
  ,(66, 70)
  ,(67, 64)
  ,(67, 66)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.pid
from t t1
join t t2
  on t1.pid = t2.pid
where
  t1.cid = 65 and t2.cid = 66
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc37/2/0)**:

```
| pid |
|-----|
|  60 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну например так:

```
select product_id FROM table WHERE category_id in (65, 66) group by product_id having count(product_id)=2;
```

если cвязка product_id => category_id уникальна.